# Table inside a Tablecell - nested Tables with Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

Hello I am working with apache POI and i have to create docx files with it.
Now I iterate over an html-document and fetch the tags to create a valid docx document.

When i have a table inside a tablecell there is no way to display that correct.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: left">Status</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>test</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It's no problem to load a correct file with nested tables from docx.

```
     FileOutputStream fos = null;
            XWPFDocument document = null;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(docRes);
                if (fileType == docType.DOCX) {
                    try {
                        String fileName = "D:\\test.docx";

                        if (!(fileName.endsWith(".doc") || fileName.endsWith(".docx"))) {
                            throw new FileFormatException();
                        } else {
                            XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(fileName));
                            List<XWPFTable> table = doc.getTables();

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

When I save this file again I get a nested Table in Word with POI.

But how can I create a nested table without loading a correct docx file?

I check many options but the already the simplistic solutions don't work.

```
            document = new XWPFDocument();
            XWPFTable tableOne = document.createTable();
            XWPFTableRow tableOneRow1 = tableOne.getRow(0);
            XWPFTableRow tableOneRow2 = tableOne.createRow();
            tableOneRow1.getCell(0).setText("Test");
            tableOneRow1.addNewTableCell();
            tableOneRow1.getCell(1).setText("Test");
            tableOneRow2.getCell(0).setText("Test");
            tableOneRow2.addNewTableCell();
            tableOneRow2.getCell(1).setText("include nestedTable");

            XWPFTable tableTwo = document.createTable();
            XWPFTableRow tableTwoRow1 = tableTwo.getRow(0);
            tableTwoRow1.getCell(0).setText("Test");
            tableTwoRow1.addNewTableCell();
            tableTwoRow1.getCell(0).setText("nestedTable");

            tableOneRow2.getCell(1).insertTable(0, tableTwo);
```

The difference to the variant which is direclty load from a docx is that in the selfmade solution the document has two tables in the document root.

What can I do to build nested tables?

Thank you

wishes Felix

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t tested this, but you might want to take a look at the documentation of the class XWPFTableCell
The methode `public void insertTable(int pos,XWPFTable table)` seems to be just what you are looking for.

Comment: thx, but how you can see I use this method in my last instruction. And yes you're right this method looks ok but she does'nt the right for me.

Comment: Sorry seems i missed that line. I actually tested the function myself but it seems it does nothing (or maybe i did it wrong). Last year i needed to create nested tables too and wasn´t able to find a solution which is actully pretty sad. I once read a thread from the poi mailing list (or something like that), but i weren´t able to find it know. There  a solution was mentioned but the older poi version i was requiered to use didn´t support that feature. Maybe if you have the time you can find that thread.

Answer (score 0):

following this [link](https://www.java-forums.org/apache-poi/95151-how-can-i-create-nestedtables-xwpf.html),it could be something like this :

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("word.docx"));
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFTable tableOne = document.createTable();
    XWPFTableRow tableOneRow1 = tableOne.getRow(0);
    XWPFTableRow tableOneRow2 = tableOne.createRow();
    tableOneRow1.getCell(0).setText("Test11");
    tableOneRow1.addNewTableCell();
    tableOneRow1.getCell(1).setText("Test12");
    tableOneRow2.getCell(0).setText("Test21");
    tableOneRow2.addNewTableCell();

    XWPFTableCell cell = tableOneRow2.getCell(1);
    CTTbl ctTbl = cell.getCTTc().addNewTbl();
    ctTbl = cell.getCTTc().addNewTbl();
    CTTblPr tblPr = ctTbl.addNewTblPr();
    cell.removeParagraph(0);
    cell.getCTTc().addNewP();

    XWPFTable tableTwo = new XWPFTable(ctTbl,cell);
    XWPFTableRow tableTwoRow1 = tableTwo.getRow(0);
    tableTwoRow1.getCell(0).setText("nestedTable11");
    tableTwoRow1.addNewTableCell();
    tableTwoRow1.getCell(1).setText("nestedTable12");

    document.write(out);
    out.close();
}
```

or use insertNewTbl(XmlCursor cursor) method:

```
        XWPFParagraph paragraph = tablerow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0);
    XmlCursor cursor = paragraph.getCTP().newCursor();
    XWPFTable tableTwo = tablerow.getCell(1).insertNewTbl(cursor);
```